# python telebot и sqlite3 (Recursive use of cursors not allowed)

Tags: python, sqlite3, telebot

Есть телеграм бот, который отправляет сообщения, получая информацию из бд sqlite3:

```
@bot.message_handler(regexp=config[language]['cat_phones'])
def handle_text(message):
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM lots')
    for row in cursor:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '{0}\n{1}\n<b> {2:,} {3}</b>\n<b> {4:,} {3}</b>'.format(
        row[3], row[5], row[8], row[1], row[8]/100*20), parse_mode='HTML')
```

когда 2 человека одновременно жмут эту кнопку, то возникает ошибка `Recursive use of cursors not allowed`
И вот, только перед запуском бота я узнал, что sqlite3 не поддерживает многопточность.

**Вопросы:**

1. Каким образом можно решить эту проблему не переходя на другой тип бд??
2. Какие бд поддерживают многопоточность??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо перейти на `postgresql`. А пока для быстрого старта есть костыль:

```
import threading

lock = threading.Lock()

@bot.message_handler(regexp=config[language]['cat_phones'])
def handle_text(message):
    with lock:
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM lots')
        data = list(cursor)
    for row in data:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '{0}\n{1}\n<b> {2:,} {3}</b>\n<b> {4:,} {3}</b>'.format(
        row[3], row[5], row[8], row[1], row[8]/100*20), parse_mode='HTML')
```

Comment: А можешь сказать разницу в данном случае между postgresql и mysql?

Comment: Ну, разницы в общем случае нет

Answer (score 0):

Нужно убрать "interval" из bot.polling() в конце кода, где запускаешь бота